# jquery highlights(change color) specific <p class='x'> text </p>

Tags: jquery, class, highlight

im new in jquery but im trying my best. 
    Here's the problem, i have this "formulary" with some questions i made with  and its working fine.
    but i need to highlight some paragraph on the text when the guy marks the correct option.

```
heres some part of the structure( if you want i'll put the whole thing) 


<p>  text  text  text  text  <p class="class1"> TEXT I NEED TO HIGHLIGHT WHEN DUDE SELECT'S RIGHT OPTION<p>  text  text  text  <p>

function verificaQuestao1(){
 resetaAlternativaQuestoes1();
 <!-- Letra A -->
 if($('#questao1_a').val()==4 ){         //if OPTION IS CORRECT
 mudaCorTextoParagrafo("#q1Alt_a","green",20);   //changes color to green
 $("#q1SimbCerto_a").show();                      // shows correct .jpg
 $("#q1SimbErrado_a").hide();                   //dont care
                         //HERE IS THE PART I SHOULD HIGHLIGHT SOME SPECIFIC <P ="CLASS> 
 }
 else{
 mudaCorTextoParagrafo("#q1Alt_a","red",20);enter code here
 $("#q1SimbCerto_a").hide();
 $("#q1SimbErrado_a").show();
```

Comment: If there will be multiple <p class="class1"> elements, then you should add an alternative way to Id them; ID and/or name.   This will allow you to select that specific element, then to highlight you could call .css and set the background or foreground colors (or both).

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  How to form a selector for that paragraph?  How to set the CSS?  The best CSS for a highlighted effect?

Answer (score 0):

Well your question isn't exactly clear. But here's a small demo to get you going:

### HTML

```
<p>
    <b>Option 1:</b>  Dogs are <span id="o1">just as cool</span> as cats. <br>
    <b>Option 2:</b>  Dogs are <span id="o2">not as cool</span> as cats.
</p>
    <b><span id="comment">Please select the correct answer<span></b> 
    <br><br>

    <button type="button" id="b1">Option 1 is correct</button>
    <button type="button" id="b2">Option 2 is correct</button> 
    <br><br>
    <button type="button" id="b3">Show answers</button>
```

### CSS

```
.correct { background-color:lime; }

.wrong   { background-color:red; }

#comment { background-color:silver; }
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#b1").click(function() {
          $("#o1").addClass('wrong');
          if ($("#o2").hasClass('correct')) { $("#o2").removeClass('correct'); }
          $("#comment").text('You have selected the wrong answer. Please try again');
    });

    $("#b2").click(function() {
          $("#o2").addClass('correct');
          if ($("#o1").hasClass('wrong')) { $("#o1").removeClass('wrong'); }
          $("#comment").text('That is correct!');
    });

    $("#b3").click(function() {
          $("#o1").addClass('wrong');
          $("#o2").addClass('correct');
          $("#comment").text('Don\'t cheat!');
    });
});
```

### Demo

You can find the working demo [by clicking this link](http://jsfiddle.net/AGpRM/).

Note that there are many ways to achieve what you're trying to do. If you have any remaining questions after examining my code, please make sure that what you are asking is concise and clear.

Hope this helps you out. Good luck.